# Override Eventbrite Register Button

Tags: eventbrite

Have anyone tried overriding the Eventbrite "Register" button? Essentially,I am looking to make an api call whenever person registers/RSVPs to the Eventbrite event.

So far my exploration has not yield any outcome. Let me know if anyone have any pointers to help me explore further.

Thank you in advance! 
Sourabh

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not directly overriding the register button, you can trigger a webhook on a new registration, which would allow your application to process some logic. The webhook will not send the attendee information, but allows it to be looked up by an API call back to Eventbrite. For more information see https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/api_overview/webhooks/